# Shortcode not staying inside div tag

Tags: php, shortcode

Using this php to show a signup form in my template file:

```
<div style="border: 3px solid green; margin-top: 1em; height: auto">
<h2>Blog notifications</h2>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[forminator_form id="9979"]'); ?>
</div>
```

Looking like this:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CGHp6ezgzeyPtbjA3zhuNAQ9VmmUEjd3

That white block at the bottom is just another div that follows.

The shortcode is not being recognised by the div and is displaying outside it. Not sure why this is.

thanks,

Comment: try: `<div style="border: 3px solid green; margin-top: 1em; height: auto; float: left; width: 100%;">`

Comment: DinhTv it worked:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=13IzcPoGgaDEin06IEDL8atid5VvWgdmC

although div that follows is coming up underneath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your form has a float property. So just add overflow hidden to parent div.

Take a look here: https://codepen.io/zecka/pen/jObvbmG

your code can be like that:

```php
<div style="border: 3px solid green; margin-top: 1em; height: auto; overflow: hidden">
<h2>Blog notifications</h2>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[forminator_form id="9979"]'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: ZecKa it did the trick:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Fo7bbyhW0K_UqY4xUmPXr4k5_H-NhzI7

Comment: Am I supposed to click "Post Your Answer" if this is now resolved for me, or do I only do that if I came up with the answer myself?

Comment: @MatJon There should be an option to mark ZecKa's answer as accepted, but I believe there's a short wait period before it appears.